# C# Web browser Enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem using the Enter key to navigate the browser.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
            go_Click.PerformClick();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And my `go_Click`:

```
private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declares URL as string variable
    string url = textbox.Text;

    //if statment to determine if URL is correct
    if (url == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid URL!");
    }

    if (url.Substring(0, 3) == "www")
    {
        url = "http://" + url;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
}
```

It returns an error, the errors states that is a method, which is not valid in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line of code `go_Click.PerformClick();`

to `go_Click(null, null);`